# Using arrays or lists in a model class

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Just wondering if it is acceptable to use arrays or lists in a model class? For example if I had a class that contained data Id, date, Name A, name B, and then 10 integers which can be null would I run into problems if I just had an array of ints instead of declaring 10 different ints? Is there best practice for this?

Comment: More details please: do you want to use it in an action in MVC ? Why should be in trouble using array of ints ?

Comment: It's a matter of semantics. If those int values are representing different measurements of the same thing, then an array would be a good choice. However, if they represent different things, then an array would be a bad choice, since you will have to rely on index to differentiate between different properties.